# Dynamical System that exhibits a fold bifurcation of Limit Tori?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, bifurcation, nonlinear-dynamics

Fold Bifurcations of a fixed points (i.e. saddle node bifurcations) and Fold bifurcations of limit cycles (i.e. when a stable limit and unstable limit cycle annihilate) are observed in plenty of different dynamical systems.

Does anyone know of a dynamical system where the equivalent happens with limit tori? An unstable and stable limit torus exist in a system, and as a parameter is tuned, these steady states approach each other until they annihilate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think this system below, when $\lambda \in (0, 1)$, has a pair of two dimensional invariant tori, the dynamics on each of them is 'linear'.
Moreover, one of these two invariant tori exhibits hyperbolic dynamics in a tubular neighborhood,
(and it has a codimension one stable and unstable manifolds, i.e. these are three dimensional immersed submanifolds of the four dimensional phase space),
while the other torus is an asymptotically stable invariant torus. Observe the system is not just real analytic but polynomial.
When the parameter $0 < \lambda < 1$ approaches $1$, the two tori merge into one and their dynamics looks like saddle-node in transverse 2D direction. When 1 < $\lambda$
the tori disappear. For this example, assume $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are some frequencies and $a = b = 0.1$

\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dt}\, = \, - \, \lambda \, x \, +\,\omega_1\, y \, + \,2\,x^3 \, +\,2\, xy^2 \, - \,(x^2+y^2)^2\,x \, + \, a\,\big(\, xz^2 + xw^2 - 4x\,\big)\\
&\\
&\frac{dy}{dt} \, = \, -\,\omega_1\,x \, - \, \lambda\, y \, + \,2\,x^2y \, +\,2\, y^3 \, - \,(x^2+y^2)^2\,y \, + \, a\,\big(\, yz^2 + yw^2 - 4y\,\big)\\
&\\
&\frac{dz}{dt} \, = \,\,\,\,\, 4\, z\, + \,\omega_2 \, w \, - \, z^3\, - \, zw^2 \, + \, b \, \big(\,\lambda\,z \, - \, 2\,x^2z \, - \,2\,y^2z\, + \, (x^2 + y^2)^2 \,z \,\big)\\
&\\
&\frac{dw}{dt} \, = \, -\, \omega_2\,z \, + \, 4\,w \, - \,z^2w\, - \, w^3 \, + \, b \, \big(\,\lambda\,w \, - \, 2\,x^2w \, - \,2\,y^2w\, + \, (x^2 + y^2)^2 \,w \,\big)\\
\end{align}

How can one see this? Well, the system is created so that the dynamics simplifies after performing a pair of decoupled two dimensional polar coordinate changes, i.e.
\begin{align}
&x \, = \, r \, \cos(\phi)\\
&y \, = \, r \, \sin(\phi)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&z \, = \, \rho \, \cos(\psi)\\
&w \, = \, \rho \, \sin(\psi)
\end{align}

To shorten the calculations, observe that if we write the system as a pair of vector ODEs (or with complex numbers of you prefer), it is easier to perform the change of coordinates.
Let $$u = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} \, ,\, \,\,v = \begin{bmatrix}z \\ w \end{bmatrix}\,\, \text{ and } \,\, J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0  \end{bmatrix} $$
as well as $|u| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $|v| = \sqrt{z^2 + w^2}$. Then the system above can be abbreviated as
\begin{align}
&\frac{du}{dt} \, = \, \omega_1 J \, u \, - \, \big(\,|u|^4 - 2\,|u|^2 + \lambda\,\big)\,u \, + \, a\,\big(\,|v|^2 - 4\,\big)\,u\\
&\frac{dv}{dt} \, = \,\omega_2  J \, v \, + \, \big(\,4 - |v|^2\,\big)\,v \, + \,b\,\big(\,|u|^4 - 2\,|u|^2 + \lambda\,\big)\,v
\end{align}
A straightforward calculations show that
$$|Ju| = |u| \,,\,\,\,\,\,\, |Jv| = |v| \,,\,\,\,\,\,\, u^T \,\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{|u|^2}{2} \right)\,,\,\,\,\,\,\, v^T \,\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{|v|^2}{2} \right)$$
$$(J u)^T \frac{du}{dt} = |u|^2 \, \frac{d\phi}{dt} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, (Ju)^Tu = 0$$
$$(J v)^T \frac{dv}{dt} = |v|^2 \, \frac{d\psi}{dt} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, (Jv)^Tv = 0$$
so if you matrix multiply the first vector equation with $u^T$ and $(Ju)^T$ and the second equation with $v^T$ and $(Jv)^T$ the equations simplify and then it is easy to plug in the polar coordinates in each. If you prefer, (actually it may be simpler, use complex numbers). The result is the following system
\begin{align}
&\frac{dr}{dt} \, = \, - \,\big(\,r^4 - 2\,r^2 + \lambda \,\big)\,r\, + a\,\big(\,\rho^2-4\,\big)\, r \\
&\\
&\frac{d\rho}{dt} \, = \, \big(\,\rho^2-4\,\big) \, \rho \, 
- \,b \,\big(\,r^4 - 2\,r^2 + \lambda \,\big)\, \rho \\
&\\
&\frac{d\phi}{dt} \, = \, \omega_1\\
&\\
&\frac{d\psi}{dt} \, = \, \omega_2
\end{align}
Take $\lambda_1 > 0$ and $\lambda_2 > 0$ to be the two positive solutions of the polynomial $r^4 - 2r^2 + \lambda = 0$ (there are four solutions, two positive and two symmetrically negative, when $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ )

In these coordinates, the tori in question can be described as
$$T_1 = \Big\{ \, \big(r,\, \rho,\, \phi, \, \psi\big) \, \in \, \mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1 \times S^1\, \, \Big| \,\, r = \lambda_1, \,\, \rho = 2  \, \Big\}$$
$$T_2 = \Big\{ \, \big(r,\, \rho,\, \phi, \, \psi\big) \, \in \, \mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1 \times S^1\, \, \Big| \,\, r = \lambda_2, \,\, \rho = 2  \, \Big\}$$

My intuition tells me that if the ratio of the frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ is a Diophantine number, a highly non-rational number so to say, then the these two tori persist under small perturbations (thanks to some KAM=like theorem) and the dynamics in a neighborhood of the tori is topologically equivalent to the dynamics of this system. In other words, I think this system is structurally stable around the tori, so this phenomenon of toric saddle-node bifurcation extends to nearby polynomial or real analytic systems, close to this one.

Here is some python code that I used to plot the 2D dynamics transverse to the tori. I basically took the first two differential equations from the system in polar coordinates and plotted the phase portrait:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def F(x, y):
  return - x*(x**4 - 2*x**2 + lam) + a*x*(y**2-4), y*(4 - y**2) + b*y*(x**4 - 2*x**2 + lam)

r1 = 2.5
r2 = 2.5
resolution1 = 1000
resolution2 = 1000
X, Y  = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, r1, resolution1), np.linspace(0, r2, resolution2))

lam = 0.5
a = 0.1
b = 0.1

dXdt, dYdt = F(X, Y)

plt.streamplot(X, Y, dXdt, dYdt)
plt.axis('square')
plt.axis([0, r1, 0, r2])
plt.show()
```

$\lambda = 0.5$:

[image]

$\lambda = 1$:

[image]

$\lambda = 1.5$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems the obvious way to construct bifurcations like this is by starting with the double cylindrical coordinates you wrote the equations in. The polynomials make sense, but what is the point of multiplying the the RHS of the radial equations by an overall factor of pho and r.

Comment: Also, are you aware of any similar fold bifurcations for chaotic attractors? Though I'm unsure of what stable vs unstable chaotic attractors would look like...

Comment: @Cheyne these factors are one way to make sure the original system is polynomial and it is easy to change coordinates. Otherwise, you may get square roots or other unpleasant stuff.

Comment: @Cheyne No, I am not aware of situations like this for chaotic attractors.

Comment: Is it important that the system is polynomial in euclidean coordinates? Is this just a convenience, or is there some theorem that makes polynomial systems important?

Comment: @Cheyne No, in general it is not important, but being polynomial is more special than real analytic, plus the system is defined everywhere in 4D space, no need to figure out where its domain is. You do not want to create a system with some specified properties and then to realize that in reality these properties do not hold, because they are not in the system's domain, or some other issue like that. On top of that, usually cooking up polynomial systems with certain properties is harder.

Comment: @Cheyne  Let's not forget that polynomials are easy to implement in computer simulations, so the system has to potential to be simulated much better and faster (just with addition and multiplication) than some systems that feature analytic functions that need to be expanded in series to be computed or some smooth functions pieced together from other functions in an awkward way. In addition to that, polynomial systems actually extend in the complex domain and can be analyzed by complex analytic methods even in projective complex 4D space.

Comment: @Cheyne well, if you are asking about the importance of polynomial dynamical systems, the theory of Ponicare' or Borkhoff's normal forms is formulated in terms of resonant versus non-resonant polynomial terms. That's how the Poincare'-Andronov-Hopf bifurcation theorem is proved: the system is first brought to a normal form, truncated to be made polynomial, that polynomial form is exactly solvable (kind of like this one) and then the result is extended to the original system by Poincare-Bendixon's theorem.